# Finding $\alpha$-stable distributions by (probably) Levy's continuity theorem

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems, characteristic-functions

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be iid random variables uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$. Now let's put $$Y_n = \frac{sgn X_n}{|X_n|^{1/\alpha}}, \, n= 1,2,...,$$ with a set value $\alpha \in (0,2)$.

The goal is to:

$\textbf{(a)}$ Show that $Z_n := \frac{Y_1 + ... + Y_n}{n^{1/\alpha}} $ converges by distribution.

$\textbf{(b)}$ Find the characteristic function of the limit.

And that would mean that the limiting distribution is stable as it has its own domain of attraction consisting of $Z_n$.

My best guess is to do this by showing that the characteristic function of $Z_n$ converges to a certain function that's continuous at $t=0$ and then using the Levy's continuity theorem ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy's_continuity_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_continuity_theorem)), but I was sadly unable to do so.

Do You perhaps have other ideas that would answer this problem or maybe it's indeed solvable by Levy's theorem? If so, how?

Edit:

I've calculated that the characteristic function of $Z_n$ should be: $$\phi_{Z_n}(u) = \left[ \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 exp(iu \frac{-1}{x^{1/\alpha}} n^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}}) dx + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 exp(iu \frac{1}{x^{1/\alpha}} n^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}}) dx \right]^n,$$ which is $$\left[ \int_0^1 cos \left( \frac{ u}{(xn)^{1/\alpha}} \right) dx \right]^n$$

Edit 2:

I've found an answered question that shows what the limit should be, but still doesn't have what I need. [Symmetric alpha stable distributions with $X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n \stackrel{d}{=} n^{1/\alpha}X$ as definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2238843/symmetric-alpha-stable-distributions-with-x-1x-2-cdotsx-n-stackreld-n?rq=1)

Comment: Were you able to get an expression for the characteristic function of $Y_i$?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon No :/
The sgn and |*| functions are giving me a really hard time in finding the characteristic function rigoristically.

Comment: I am not sure that we can use Levy's theorem, because the characteristic functions of the $Y_i$ are not elementary functions by the look of it.Are you reading any particular book of which this is an exercise? Any material you were reading in which you encountered this question?

Comment: It was asked as an exercise under the chapter about Levy's theorem in my uni's lecture notes.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I will see if I can carry it forward.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I've placed an edit with the corrected characteristic

Comment: Will take that into consideration, thanks. I have given your question a +1 for your effort and willingness to clarify with me. Just struggling, may take time.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I've added further calculations. Sorry that my previous characteristic was wrong, now it should be proper.

Comment: Just saw the second edit (after waking up!) I have not explored this part of probability theory too often, so I will dip my toes, let's hope I can give you a good answer after seeing all that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**
Let $ X_1,X_2,\cdots $ be a sequence of iid random variables uniformly distributed on $ [-1,1] $.
Now let's put
\begin{equation*} Y_n=\frac{\mathrm{sgn}X_n}{|X_n|^{1/\alpha}}, \qquad n\ge 1, \end{equation*}
with a set value $ \alpha\in(0,2) $.

**(a)** Show that $ Z_n=\frac{Y_1+\cdots+Y_n}{n^{1/\alpha}} $ converges by distribution.

**(b)** Find the characteristic function of the limit.

And that would mean that the limiting distribution is stable as it has its own domain of attribution consisting of $ Z_n $

**Answer**  Let
$$ \phi_n(t)=\mathsf{E}\Big[\exp\Big(\frac{itY_1}{n^{1/\alpha}}\Big)\Big]
=\int_{0}^{1}\cos\Big(\frac{t}{(xn)^{1/\alpha}}\Big)dx. $$
Then
$$ \phi_{Z_n}(t)=\mathsf{E}[\exp(itZ_n)]=(\phi_n(t))^n. $$
Meanwhile,
\begin{align*}
 n[1-\phi_n(t)]&=n\int_0^1\Big[1-\cos\Big(\frac{t}{(nx)^{1/\alpha}}\Big)\Big]\,dx\\
 &=\alpha |t|^\alpha\int_{|t|/n^{1/\alpha}}^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos(z)}{z^{\alpha +1}}\,dz\\
 &\to  C(\alpha) |t|^\alpha, \qquad \text{as}\quad n\to\infty.
\end{align*}
where(cf. Sato, *Lévy Processes and Infinitively Divisible Distributions*, Cambridge University Press, 1999, Lemma 14.1 p.84,
or Y. S. Chow &  H. Teicher, *Probability Theory*, 3rd ed., Springer Verlag, 1997, p.469--.)
\begin{align*}
 C(\alpha)&=\alpha\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos(z)}{z^{\alpha +1}}\,dz\\
 &=\begin{cases}
  \cos\Big(\dfrac{\alpha\pi}{2}\Big)\Gamma(1-\alpha),& \alpha \in (0,1)\cup(1,2)\\
  \quad\dfrac{\pi}{2}, &\alpha=1.
 \end{cases}
\end{align*}
Then
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\phi_{Z_n}(t)=\lim_{n\to\infty}[1-(1-\phi_n(t))]^n=\exp[-C(\alpha) |t|^\alpha]. $$